# How to Execute a SQL file with multiple queries in Talend and store the result in a log or output file

Tags: talend

I want to execute a SQL file with multiple queries inside it using Talend.
To my understanding of Talend there is no straight forward way of doing it.
My SQL File contains multiple Select Statement related to Various tables.
Ex: Select age,name from Table_AB; Select count(Salary), emp_id from Emp_table; 
I have referred http://bekwam.blogspot.in/2011/02/running-file-of-sql-statements-with.html ; The queries get executed but i want to output the results of the tOracleRow to an output file or log file and send the file to an Email recipient.

What i Have Done till now is: [Talend Job to execute a SQL file with multiple queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQp5K.png)

Can Anyone please help me on how to Output the results of an tOracleRow to an output file and mail the results  to an Email recipient. I am able to do it for a single table with a schema , but confused on how to do it for various Tables and output it

Comment: tOracleRow does not return the results...one option is that you can collect the results after every sql/query in your muti-insert/drop statement file into a temp/similar table in oracle DB say logs and after execution of tOracleRow read from this table - say logs via tOracleInput and now you can use this data to write/email etc..;

Comment: @garpitmzn - I have queries related to Various Tables, So storing the results will in a temporary table would be a tougher task as you will need more schemas to relate to each different Table. I know tOracleRow doesnot return any results but is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: what results you want to send...and what are these multi insert..i dont think any of the talend output/row component will return you output all they would return is number of rows impacted or error message. I am also wondering what are these results here? are these rows inserted, deleted?

Comment: @garpitmzn- I have two different sql files:  SQLFile1: drop table2; Insert into table1();drop table2; Insert into table2();drop table3;  SQLFile2: Select * from Table1(c1,c2,c3); Select  * from Table2(c1,c2)

Comment: and for results from insert statements you can get rows inserted..for select * from table1 (c1,c2,c3) - why can't you do this via tOracleInput?

Comment: @garpitmzn- The tOracleRow doesnt provide any options for input row to be added to it.

Comment: sorry, but i am not able to understand..why you need to give input row to toraclerow..if i want to do update/delete i would use toracleoutput..toraclerow i would only use to run any script or may be fire some manually written sql..

Comment: @garpitmzn- How can i store results of multiple SQL Queries in Talend?

Comment: what does these multiple sql queries do..do they insert or update or delete or select..if they do insert, update, delete..what result you want to store..number of records impacted? if its select - you can always use toracleinput/otherinput component.....as i said earlier also - as per my experience you can only get impacted rows and not other details..yes if sql fails you can always catch the exception and error in tlogcatcher..

Comment: @garpitmzn- Can you show me a Visual Diagram of how you can Read a SQL Script with many Select queries and then execute it and store the output of the ResultSet into some File to be Emailed? I don't want to use built in query, i would like to read the SQL scripts from a SQL file preferably. Any Solutions for this?

Comment: can be done, but provided you have same select columns from tables..what i mean here is that your schema should be same..if its different then also you can do it, but will be more complex...see below. lets assume you have select statement in a csv file where each line is a select statement separated by end of line character...we do as below..

Comment: .tFileinputdelimited-->iterateforeachrow-->tJava(here you put select statement from the input csv row into globalVar say "sqlSTMT") -->OracleInput (here we use sql coming from csv which we have stored in sqlSTMT) -->tFileOutputdelimited...(here in this file we can use filename to be some variable appended to filename..like FileoutputSQL1, fileoutputSQL2...)...now you can email these logs in another flow by looping through all files..and appending them to single file..and email